# Как избавиться от значений NoneType при вычислении сходства косинусов?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Я попытался создать сходство косинусов между двумя столбцами фрейма данных с пространством «space.distance.cosine» в другом столбце, используя следующие две функции:

```
def cosine_sim(x):
    li = []
    for item in x["sent_emb"]:
        li.append(spatial.distance.cosine(item,x["quest_emb"][0]))
    return li

def predictions(train):

    train["cosine_sim"] = train.apply(cosine_sim, axis = 1)
```

Эти две колонки выглядят так:

```
    sent_emb                                            quest_emb
0   [[0.030376578, 0.044331014, 0.081356354, 0.062...   [[0.01491953, 0.021973763, 0.021364095, 0.0393...
1   [[0.030376578, 0.044331014, 0.081356354, 0.062...   [[0.04444952, 0.028005758, 0.030357722, 0.0375...
2   [[0.030376578, 0.044331014, 0.081356354, 0.062...   [[0.03949683, 0.04509903, 0.018089347, 0.07667...
   ...
```

Тем не менее, я получил «TypeError», кажется, что некоторые значения - «NoneType» и «float». Знаете ли вы, как я могу фильтровать данные такого рода, чтобы установить его в zro или два, что не мешает мне применить мои

```
TypeError: ("unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'float'", 'occurred at index 473')

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-af28fc11a9d3> in <module>()
----> 1 predicted = predictions(train)

<ipython-input-22-1699cf33d87c> in predictions(train)
      1 def predictions(train):
      2 
----> 3     train["cosine_sim"] = train.apply(cosine_sim, axis = 1)
      4     train["diff"] = (train["quest_emb"] - train["sent_emb"])**2
      5     train["euclidean_dis"] = train["diff"].apply(lambda x: list(np.sum(x, axis = 1)))

~/Documents/programming/mybot/mybotenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in apply(self, func, axis, broadcast, raw, reduce, result_type, args, **kwds)
   6012                          args=args,
   6013                          kwds=kwds)
-> 6014         return op.get_result()
   6015 
   6016     def applymap(self, func):

~/Documents/programming/mybot/mybotenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in get_result(self)
    140             return self.apply_raw()
    141 
--> 142         return self.apply_standard()
    143 
    144     def apply_empty_result(self):

~/Documents/programming/mybot/mybotenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in apply_standard(self)
    246 
    247         # compute the result using the series generator
--> 248         self.apply_series_generator()
    249 
    250         # wrap results

~/Documents/programming/mybot/mybotenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in apply_series_generator(self)
    275             try:
    276                 for i, v in enumerate(series_gen):
--> 277                     results[i] = self.f(v)
    278                     keys.append(v.name)
    279             except Exception as e:

<ipython-input-20-276aa09bc25e> in cosine_sim(x)
      2     li = []
      3     for item in x["sent_emb"]:
----> 4         li.append(spatial.distance.cosine(item,x["quest_emb"][0]))
      5     return li

~/Documents/programming/mybot/mybotenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/spatial/distance.py in cosine(u, v, w)
    742     # cosine distance is also referred to as 'uncentered correlation',
    743     #   or 'reflective correlation'
--> 744     return correlation(u, v, w=w, centered=False)
    745 
    746 

~/Documents/programming/mybot/mybotenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/spatial/distance.py in correlation(u, v, w, centered)
    693         u = u - umu
    694         v = v - vmu
--> 695     uv = np.average(u * v, weights=w)
    696     uu = np.average(np.square(u), weights=w)
    697     vv = np.average(np.square(v), weights=w)

TypeError: ("unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'float'", 'occurred at index 473')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-нибудь так?

```
for item in x["sent_emb"]:
    sent_emb = item if item is not None else FALLBACK_VALUE
    quest_emb = x["quest_emb"][0] if x["quest_emb"][0] is not None else FALLBACK_VALUE
    li.append(spatial.distance.cosine(sent_emb, quest_emb))
```

Comment: Что такое `li` ? Разве это не может сделать двусмысленный тест? с `item or FALLBACK_VALUE`? Моя цель состояла в том, чтобы вычислить эти косинусные расстояния.

Comment: Вы меня спрашиваете? `li` - это список из вашего кода. Я просто добавил к вашему коду две строчки, заменяющие `None` на некоторое страховочное значение, любое какое вам будет удобнее.

Comment: Извините, я был потерян